# How to move circular radial gradient slightly to top?

Tags: html, css, gradient

How can I move radial gradiant slightly more upwards while maintaining same circular width and heigth?

```css
div {
  line-height: 100px;  
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;  
  width: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse 115px 102px, #fff, #516e8e);
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

I have found this solution, but then the gradient becomes stretched.

```
background: radial-gradient(at top,red,yellow,green);
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWgeyw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the position of gradient using `at` as follows:

```
radial-gradient(115px 102px at center top, #90aed0, #516e8e)
```

You can use keywords, `px` or `%` values to define position of the shape:

```css
.box-2 {
  background: radial-gradient(115px 102px at center top, #90aed0, #516e8e);
}

.box {
  line-height: 100px;  
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;  
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p class="box box-2">text</p>
```

***Note:*** As you have defined specific size i.e. `115px 102px` so there is no need to use `ellipse` or `circle` keyword.